Add Date column base on other columns in Bigquery
I'm using Bigquery and trying to find a way to add a new date column based on a date that already exists.
In the example below, the first record starts on 2024-01-04 (DeliveryDate). Which means the cost for this day was 178086.0 and so on.
Input Data
DeliveryDate    Month   PlanSystemId    cost
2024-01-04     2024-01  92059548         178086.0
2024-01-06     2024-01  92059548         165132.0
2024-01-07     2024-01  92059548         180159.0
2024-01-09     2024-01  92059548         178991.0

I need to add a Date column that starts at the start of the month (2024-01) and put 0 in the cost column because we haven't received any data from those dates.
Output Data
Date        DeliveryDate    Month   PlanSystemId    cost
2024-01-01   null          2024-01  92059548         0
2024-01-02   null          2024-01  92059548         0
2024-01-03   null          2024-01  92059548         0
2024-01-04   2024-01-04    2024-01  92059548         178086.0
2024-01-05   null          2024-01  92059548         0
2024-01-06   2024-01-06    2024-01  92059548         165132.0
2024-01-07   2024-01-07    2024-01  92059548         180159.0
2024-01-08   null          2024-01  92059548         0
2024-01-09   2024-01-09    2024-01  92059548         178991.0
2024-01-10   null          2024-01  92059548         0
.....
2024-01-31   null          2024-01  92059548         0

I did a CTE that covers all days of the month, then I do a left join with the source table to get all the dates, but I can't seem to populate any other columns with data.
I hope you can help me find a solution.
Thanks in advance

Would there always be just one PlanSystemId value, or could there be multiple values?

hi, yes, there are multiple values ​​for PlansystemID. This ID is like a product ID, so we can have many different products

One canonical way to handle this problem is to use a calendar table, which is along the lines of what you were already doing.  Consider the following approach:
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT dt
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2024-01-01', '2024-01-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS dt
),
systems AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT PlanSystemId
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    d.dt,
    t.DeliveryDate,
    PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', d.dt) AS Month,
    s.PlanSystemId,
    COALESCE(t.cost, 0) AS cost
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN systems s
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.DeliveryDate = d.dt AND
       t.PlanSystemId = s.PlanSystemId
ORDER BY
    s.PlanSystemId,
    d.dt;

In the above query, we generate a set of all dates desired to appear in the report.  Here I am simply including all dates in January, 2024, but you may extend this as needed.  We also generate a set of all distinct PlanSystemId values.  In the case of both CTEs, you may choose to replace them with bona fide tables as needed.  Then we left join to your current table to generate the desired report.

Thanks Tim, your solution works. I was wondering if you can expalin me why you use a cross join

@AlejandroRuiz Well the cross join generates an intermediate table of all dates and systems.  From this, we left join to your table to generate the report you want.

The concept you want to implement is named "Virtual column". A column calculated on the values of other column in the same row. However this concept do not exist in BigQuery and you can't achieve it in a table.
The solution is to have a view, or a materialized view, to calculate this field but it's impossible on the source table itself.
